# logging with morgan only shows 127.0.0.1 for :remote-addr in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, logging

i have a nodejs/express application and am logging with morgan: 

    `var morgan = require ("morgan");
    var app = express();
    app.use(morgan(':date[iso] :remote-addr :method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms'));`

but in my logfiles (redirected from 'npm start') i find lines like this:

`2014-12-21T10:02:59.365Z 127.0.0.1 GET / 304 - - 2.389 ms`

showing 127.0.0.1 as remote address for all requests. i do use angular's $routeProvider after the index.html is loaded but even the / request returns 127.0.0.1.

`app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);
    app.get('*', function (req, res) {
      res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
      res.charset = 'UTF-8';
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/pub/index.html');
    });`

am i missing something? shouldn't the actual requester be logged here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is your server behind a proxy?

Try:

`app.enable("trust proxy");`

(Insert line before using morgan middleware)

Comment: i dont know enough about express but 'trust proxy' seems to work! not sure what it does exacly but i'll leave it in there :) tnx

Answer (score 1):

Two conditions must be met.
As **pasimako** showed code:

```
app.enable("trust proxy");
```

and with nginx configuration (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66992968/8015526)):

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

For me works only that way.